# Google analytics with Power BI

Tags: google-analytics, powerbi

I am trying to integrate Google Analytics data with Microsoft Power BI, however, the results are different in Power BI from the actual Google Analytics report. Why is this happening? Is there any other API that helps you integrate Google Analytics data with Power BI data?

Googe

Answer (score 0):

When you use the standard GA connector in the PBI, if you put a period longer than 30 days, it applies an algorithm on the data, and brings false data to periods longer than 30 days, use the GA APIS.